# Extract Multiple Instances of the Same Match from a String

Tags: python, regex

I need to extract the `value` of all instances of pattern match of `ssid` in a string.

```
interface_info = '''Interface wlan1-cabin-2  
                ifindex 37  
                wdev 0x300000003  
                addr 06:53:1a:4e:07:02  
                ssid SSID3  
                type AP  
                channel 6 (2437 MHz), width: 20 MHz, center1: 2437 MHz  
        Interface wlan1-cabin-1  
                ifindex 36  
                wdev 0x300000002  
                addr 06:53:1a:4e:07:01  
                ssid SSIDTEST2  
                type AP  
                channel 6 (2437 MHz), width: 20 MHz, center1: 2437 MHz  
        Interface wlan1  
                ifindex 7
                wdev 0x300000001  
                addr 06:53:1a:4e:07:00  
                ssid SSID1 
                type AP  
                channel 6 (2437 MHz), width: 20 MHz, center1: 2437 MHz  '''

ssid_regex = re.compile('ssid (\w+)')              
ssid_extract = re.search(ssid_regex,interface_info)

print (ssid_extract)
```

returns a value for first match only. I need to extract the value of every `ssid` match [SSID3, SSIDTEST2, SSID1}.
SSID3

Actual SSID3
expected [SSID3, SSIDTEST2, SSID1]

Comment: Try `ssid_regex.findall(interface_info)`? https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall

Answer (score 0):

## !/usr/bin/env python

import re
interface_info = '''
phy#3
Interface wlan1-cabin-1
ifindex 36
wdev 0x300000002
addr 06:53:1a:4e:07:01
ssid SSIDTEST3
type AP
channel 6 (2437 MHz), width: 20 MHz, center1: 2437 MHz
Interface wlan1
ifindex 7
wdev 0x300000001
addr 06:53:1a:4e:07:00
ssid SSIDTEST2
type AP
channel 6 (2437 MHz), width: 20 MHz, center1: 2437 MHz
phy#2
Interface wlan0
ifindex 6
wdev 0x200000001
addr 02:ac:1a:4e:07:00
ssid SSID1
type AP
channel 149 (5745 MHz), width: 80 MHz, center1: 5775 MHz

'''
interface_info = re.sub(re.compile('^\s+', re.MULTILINE), '', interface_info)
ssid_regex = re.compile('ssid (\w+)')
ssid_extract = re.findall(ssid_regex, interface_info[interface_info.index("Interface wlan1"):])

print (ssid_extract)
print (type(ssid_extract))

## print(str(interface_info))

Comment: Nice. Worked for me. Thanks for prompt response.

Comment: How can findall be applied starting with a specific line in the file? Say search for all `ssid` match starting from `Interface wlan1-cabin-1` till end of file.

Comment: You could pass `findall()` the part of the string starting with that string.  `interface_info = interface_info[interface_info.index("Interface wlan1-cabin-1"):]`

Comment: In the string var `interface_info`, I would like to remove all leading edge spaces from each line before processing/parsing the string. I have tried `strip() and lstrip()` - did not work. Any suggestions?

Comment: That's a good candidate for a new question ( stringing questions together in comments to answers from previous questions makes it impossible for others to learn from questions) I think you're asking, how to remove spaces preceding newlines in a string.

Comment: Is it possible to pass both a start location and and an end point in the string to findall()? For example, start the search at phy#3 and end at phy#2.

Comment: Is it possible to pass both a start location and and an end point in the string to findall()?  Example1, start the search at phy#3 and end at phy#2. Example2, for each `phy#x`, given `Interface wlanx`, findall() ssids till `next phy#x'